# Openscad : linear_extrude won't scale

Tags: openscad

This simple code :

```
linear_extrude(height = 10, scale =2) { 
  circle(r = 1); 
}
```

create a cylinder instead of scaling the circle during the extrusion.

Result:
[image: bad scaling result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine with the latest release version (2015.03-2). I'd suggest to check the version of OpenSCAD you are running. It might be an old release which does not support the scale parameter.

Comment: exactly. I spend some time to update it on Ubuntu, but it's working now. Thanks